# rand() Function to give a 32-bit random unsigned int

Tags: c, random, bit

I have some trouble coding a Function that takes 3 rand()- values and generates a 32-bit value. Specifically it has to be 15-bit from the first rand() operation; then attaching another 15-bit from the second rand() operation; and lastly attaching 2-bits from the last rand() operation;

My idea was something like this

`unsigned int x = (rand()<<17 | rand()<<2 ) | rand()>>13;`

However i don´t think this function gives me values of the entire unsigned int range, my guess it has something to do with the fact that rand() gives you at least a value of 32767 (as far as i understand).

I hope someone can help me out.

Cheers

Comment: (a) There is no actual question asked in your post. (b) `rand` does not give you “at least a value of 32767”. In any C implementation, it has some maximum value it may return, and that value is at least 32,767. `rand` returns integers from 0 to some maximum `RAND_MAX`, and `RAND_MAX` is at least 32,767. (c) `rand() << 17` can overflow `int`, so you need `(unsigned int) rand() << 17`. (d) If `rand()` may return values greater than 32,767 , then `(rand()<<17 | rand()<<2 ) | rand()>>13` overlaps them; some overlapping bits will be combined with OR.

Comment: You can fix the overlap problem by reducing the `rand` result to 15 bits before applying `|`. Or, if you know the `rand` implementation being used returns only 15-bit numbers (integers from 0 to 32,767), you can ignore that; `(unsigned int) rand() << 17 | rand() << 2 | rand() >> 13` is okay, presuming `unsigned int` is 32 bits and `rand` returns a value less than 2^29 (so that `rand() << 2` does not overflow).

Comment: I would use perhaps `((unsigned)rand() << 17) ^ (rand() << 8) ^ rand()`

Comment: @WeatherVane: Then you need the added assurance that `RAND_MAX`+1 is a power of two.

Comment: @EricPostpischil yes: I was considering the MS VC version where `RAND_MAX` is `32767`

Comment: Rather than trying to stich together values from crappy rand function, you could just roll your own rand function. For example, [xorshift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xorshift) is quite simple to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with your code. First of all `rand` returns `int` and not `unsigned int`, and if your `unsigned int` is 32 bits, then bit shift left to position 17 is invalid if top bit is set. The second problem is that if `rand` indeed does return *more* than 15 bits then you're getting too many. One simple fix for both of these would be to `&` with `0x7fffu` - that would ensure only 15 bits are set *and* that the resulting value is `unsigned`:

```
unsigned int x = ((rand() & 0x7fffu)<<17 | (rand() & 0x7fffu)<<2 ) | (rand() & 0x7fffu)>>13;
```

---

Another one, if you know the values are *truly* independent (Edit: and as Eric noticed, also a power of two), would be to use xor `^` instead of `or` - this would ensure that all values are still possible.

---

Note though that any random number generator that returns values only from 0 to 32767 is a suspect for being *really bad* and it is very likely that the lower-order bits are not very independent and it can be that you will end up not being able to generate all values nevertheless...